# Regex How to remove last ; from a string?

Tags: .net, xml, regex, sharepoint

I have this `(/\;$/, "");` to remove last ; from a string. but the result is same as input.

Comment: You don't need the escape `;`. Try it without escaping and tell what happens. On the other hand, what method are you calling on which object to perform the replacement ?

Comment: Would be great if you could give some example input. Is the `;` the last entry on one line? I don't understand this sharepoint-syntax but the regex-part shouldn't be that tough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work for you:

```
\;(?=[^;]*$)
```

So your replacement code would become:

```
(\;(?=[^;]*$), "");
```

[Here](http://regexr.com?365id) is an example of the regex working on RegExr.

Comment: Lewis: Thanks for the reply. unfortunately, I am using the RegEx SharePoint workflow and it does not take code like you provide.

Comment: No problem. I've updated my answer with a regex that should hopefully work for you.